# How do I call a child's overloaded operator from a function in the parent class which has a reference to the parent as a parameter?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading

How do I get an overloaded relational operator in a class to be called from a function in the parent class that is handed a const reference to a base class as a parameter? The following code demonstrates what I would like to do:

```
class Object 
{
public:
    virtual ~Object(void);
    virtual int compare(Object const& obj) const;
};

int Object::compare(Object const & obj) const {
    if(this == &obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(this < &obj)
    {
        return -1;
    } else{
        return 1;
    }
}

class Integer: public Object
{
private:
    int myInt;
public:
    Integer(int i);
    bool operator==(const Integer& integer);
};

bool Integer::operator==(Integer const &integer) {
    if(myInt == integer.myInt)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How do I get the compare function in the base class to call the == operator in the child class, keeping in mind I have other child classes as well?

I have tried dynamic_cast<> but for some reason it wont work.

Comment: Note you just compare addresses not objects in base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another virtual method `isEqual` to connect with the `Integer::operator==`.

The only requirement is to keep the `Object::isEqual` signature in the class `Integer`. You should also keep in mind that your `Object::compare` method can be (accidentally) called on objects of different types.

```
class Object 
{
protected:
    virtual bool isEqual(Object const& obj) const
      { return this == &obj; }
public:
    virtual ~Object(void);
    virtual int compare(Object const& obj) const;
};

int Object::compare(Object const & obj) const {
    if(isEqual(obj))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(this < &obj)
    {
        return -1;
    } else{
        return 1;
    }
}

class Integer: public Object
{
private:
    int myInt;
protected:
    virtual bool isEqual(Object const& obj) const
      { if (!dynamic_cast<const Integer*>(&obj))
          return false;
        return *this == (const Integer&) obj;
      }
public:
    Integer(int i);
    bool operator==(const Integer& integer);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now if I want the same functionality for another child class I simply implement the isEqual in the other child class?

Comment: @Keagansed Yes it should work. You can also override the method compare in the child classes to directly call the `operator==`. The default pointer comparison when `isEqual` returns `false` is likely to be wrong or at least hard to debug (not reproductible in non-debug mode).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. What I've done is pretty much what you said.. I overrided compare in the child class to test if a dynamic cast is possible, if it wasn't I returned Object::compare(obj) which simply compared the addresses as I was doing so it at least has a default operation and if it was possible I directly called the operator== as you did in the isEqual. I wil I could upvote your answer but I dont have enough reputation to do so.. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
#include <iostream>

class Object 
{
public:
    virtual ~Object(void) {};
    int compare(Object const& obj) const;
    virtual bool operator==(Object const& integer) const = 0;
    virtual bool operator<(Object const& integer) const = 0;
    virtual bool operator>(Object const& integer) const = 0;
};

int Object::compare(Object const& obj) const
{
    if(*this == obj)
        return 0;
    else if(*this < obj)
        return -1;
    else return 1;
}

class Integer: public Object
{
private:
    int myInt;
public:
    Integer(int i) : myInt(i) { };
    virtual bool operator==(Object const& integer) const override;
    virtual bool operator<(Object const& integer) const override;
    virtual bool operator>(Object const& integer) const override;
};

bool Integer::operator==(Object const& integer) const
{
    return myInt == dynamic_cast<Integer const&>(integer).myInt;
}

bool Integer::operator<(Object const& integer) const
{
    return myInt < dynamic_cast<Integer const&>(integer).myInt;
}

bool Integer::operator>(Object const& integer) const
{
    return myInt > dynamic_cast<Integer const&>(integer).myInt;
}
int main()
{
    Integer a(2), b(2), c(3);
    std::cout << a.compare(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.compare(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.compare(a) << std::endl;
}
```

---

But in reality you should just provide virtual `compare` function in inherited class like so:

```
class Object 
{
public:
    virtual ~Object(void) {};
    virtual int compare(Object const& obj) const = 0;
};

class Integer: public Object
{
private:
    int myInt;
public:
    Integer(int i) : myInt(i) { };
    virtual int compare(Object const& object) const override;
    bool operator==(Integer const& integer) const;
    bool operator<(Integer const& integer) const;
    bool operator>(Integer const& integer) const;
};

int Integer::compare(Object const& object) const
{
    Integer const& ref = dynamic_cast<Integer const&>(object);
    if(ref == *this)
        return 0;
    else if(ref > *this)
        return 1;
    else return -1;
}

bool Integer::operator==(Integer const& integer) const
{
    return myInt == integer.myInt;
}

bool Integer::operator<(Integer const& integer) const
{
    return myInt > integer.myInt;
}

bool Integer::operator>(Integer const& integer) const
{
    return myInt < integer.myInt;
}
```

Comment: I get an error that says can't compare structures if I use *this == obj